# Calculating the difference between two columns on the same measure for different years

Tags: sql, database

Hi I am new to tables can anyone help me how to calculate the difference between two columns in table.

The table looks like this

```
Area     2016 sales    2017 sales    difference
-------- ------------- ------------- ----------
India    5000          4500          -500
```

I am not able to calculate the difference like this in tableau while in excel is too easy

Can anyone help me

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a spoon feeding site.  You have to make an attempt to solve the problem on your own.  If your attempt fails, show what you tried, and what happened.  Also, specify your database engine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put dimension for years on the columns, put measure on Text (marks tab)
2. Right click green meausure pile -> Add table calculation
3. Select Table Calculation "Difference from", "Table across"
4. Confirm

Now in 2017 column you'll see the difference between 2017 and 2016 and null in column 2016

To return sales redesign your worksheet like this (you can save sales with triangle calculation by dragging it on measures tab) 
[worksheet design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkhfs.png)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I got the above result but just wanted to see whether I can get difference in a seperate column not on the same as 2017 column